# What's the old guy (Chuck?)'s problem in the end of Better Call Saul episode 4 of season 1

Tags: better-call-saul

In Better Call Saul episode 4 of season 1 (the one aired on Feb 23, 2015), there's an old guy (Chuck?) in the end, who James hid the newspaper from, and apparently can't go outside without a shield thing. Does he have some sort of disease, if yes, what is it?